# Determining whether a Mongo document is the first one with a particular attribute

Tags: mongodb

I need to produce a report on a set of documents with timestamps between two dates.  The report needs to list each document, but it also needs to include a field for each document to indicate whether it's the first document in its group, which is indicated by an attribute.

There's a slight complication in the fact that although only documents between the two dates should be included, documents before the start date need to be considered when deciding if each document is the first it its set.

E.g. given the data

```
{ "_id": 1, "group": "A", "timestamp": "2015-01-01" }
{ "_id": 2, "group": "B", "timestamp": "2015-01-02" }
{ "_id": 3, "group": "A", "timestamp": "2015-01-03" }
{ "_id": 4, "group": "C", "timestamp": "2015-01-04" }
{ "_id": 5, "group": "B", "timestamp": "2015-01-05" }
{ "_id": 6, "group": "C", "timestamp": "2015-01-06" }
```

Generating a report from 2015-01-02 to 2015-01-05 would return

```
{ "_id": 2, "group": "B", "timestamp": "2015-01-02", "first": 1 }
{ "_id": 3, "group": "A", "timestamp": "2015-01-03", "first": 0 }
{ "_id": 4, "group": "C", "timestamp": "2015-01-04", "first": 1 }
{ "_id": 5, "group": "B", "timestamp": "2015-01-05", "first": 0 }
```

Currently I'm doing this by sorting all documents by group then timestamp, then looping over the entire dataset keeping track of the previous row to decide if a row inside the date range is the first of its type.  With a large dataset this is very slow - it feels as though there must be a better way involving grouping or something clever but my Mongo skills aren't up to the job - any suggestions?

Comment: Are your timestamps actually saved as strings in your db? If so, I would strongly recommend changing the schema design so that the timestamp field holds valid date objects.

Comment: Why would `C` be first? I don't seem to get what you want. Please elaborate. And of course @chridam is right: ISODates are better comparable against each other and need less space (8 bytes for a 64bit int vs a 10 byte string).

Comment: @chridam Good point, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg C would be first because it's the first document in group C (going by timestamp).